# Will I have to rewrite any major pieces of code for iis7.5?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Does anybody know if there are any major changes in IIS7.5 that is coming with Windows 7 that will require rewriting all or a portion of a major website (CMS). Obviously not knowing my code, it is hard to judge this, but I haven't found any announcements of what is expected in IIS7.5 and would like to get a heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect any breaking changes. [This document shows the changes.](http://blogs.iis.net/mailant/archive/2009/01/11/iis7-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx)

IIS7 introduced a lot of new features, and was a somewhat dramatic change. IIS 7.5 just builds on on that. Some features that one can now download via the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/Web/downloads/platform.aspx)  (like FTP 7.5) will be included in IIS 7.5 from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

I've imported a few of my projects over to Win7's IIS and if you're coming from an [IIS7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms689429.aspx) environment then everything hums (so far).  If you're coming from a lower version of IIS then there are a few things that need to be taken into consideration (ex. system.webServer node in your web.config).

You're right however, I have no idea what your code is other than a CMS.  From personal experience, I've encountered no problems.